# What will happen if we modify the "Manager" property inside the sharepoint user profile service

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile, user-profile-service, active-directory

I am not sure how the sync between AD and sharepoint online users profile service work. let say i modify the sharepoint user profile service property named Manager for a user, and inside AD this user does not have any manager specified. Then will the manager value i specified inside the sharepoint user profile service get overridden to match the value inside AD (which is null or empty)? I mentioned the Manager property as an example, but i am referring to the whole sharepoint online user profile service's properties.

in our case we use the DirSync for our office 365 users.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

It will be overwritten with a null value if the user has no manager specified.

Comment: thanks for the helpful/valuable reply. so in this case we should always modify the AD and not the SP user profile service? second question, is there any property inside the sharepoint user profile service that will not have a source AD property? or all the built-in properties inside the SP user profile service must be updated from AD and not directly inside the SP user profile service?

Comment: Yes, you should be updating from Active Directory. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Information-about-user-profile-synchronization-in-SharePoint-Online-177eb196-5887-43c9-84c3-b98a43d35129 for properties that are replicated between AAD and SPO.

Comment: ok thanks for the link @ https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Information-about-user-profile-synchronization-in-SharePoint-Online-177eb196-5887-43c9-84c3-b98a43d35129 , but inside the SP user profile service's properties i can see many properties that are not in the link such as Manger, Skills, Hire date, and much more.. and i think those are been synced from AD as well.. so not sure why they are not mentioned on the link..

Comment: can you advice on my above comment please?

Comment: So the sync is always one way if you are using OOTB profile synchronization option in SharePoint . This sync is from AD to SharePoint UPS . Any change in UPS does not change anything in the AD . Only the thing is if profile synchronization is enabled then any changes in User property will get overridden if it does not match the value in AD . Answering to your last question profile synchronization by defaults picks up AD properties and SP UPS properties and sync it . If you want to add additional(custom) properties for sync you might need to use MIM .

Comment: @yash.kamdar thanks for your valuable reply. i do not think we will go with the MIM approach at least at this stage. But one thing i did not understand, now inside SP online user profile service there is a list of properties (113 User Properties and 15 Organization Properties) as mentioned on the home page of the service, and all of these properties are been synced from AD, and are actually active directory properties ?  so we do not have any property inside the SP user profile service which are not an AD property?

Comment: @yash.kamdar can you advice more on my above comment ?

Comment: There are a lot of properties that are by default created by SharePoint . For example SPS-UserPrincipalName , TItle etc.. But what Profile sychronization smartly does is creates a mapping for these properties in the back end with the Active directory properties .  So technically, there are properties that are OOTB belonging to SharePoint but they get mapped with AD on the basis of their characteristics and so we feel like everything is coming from AD which is technically the right way .